# Android - Load and resize images before App start?

Tags: android, image, resize, imageview, size

In "onCreate" I have this code here:

```
    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    // ...

    imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = imgViewWidth;
    imageView2.getLayoutParams().width = imgViewWidth;
    imageView3.getLayoutParams().width = imgViewWidth;
```

Now,

1. The app starts
2. I see the background (solid color)
3. Then, the images appear

What can I do, that the resized images appear before the app starts?

Comment: When you say "app", your code is in an activity, in a fragment...?

Comment: Code is in "activity".

Comment: This solved my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861585/get-content-view-size-in-oncreate

Answer (score 0):

You can resize it in onCreate. See this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: But, why the images appear after the app starts? It looks not good.

Comment: An activity is created after onCreate method, then check the cycle of your code.

Comment: Hmm.. I resize the images under "onWindowFocusChanged" too. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I know where is the problem. In "onCreate" I can't getMeasuredWidth(). It's added to imgViewWidth. I can't get the getMeasuredWidth().